# Are there any specifics related to veganism and working out?

Tags: veganism, nutrition, sports, diet, fitness

I used to workout quite a lot when I was omnivore and vegetarian but have not visited the gym for some time because of a back injury. When transitioning from omnivore to vegetarian, I did not do any adjustments to my workouts/diet (apart from not eating meat anymore obviously).

Now I would like to start going to the gym again, but as a vegan. Apart from my protein intake, are there any other things I should take into consideration when it comes to veganism and high-intensity cardio and weight-lifting training?

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/r/veganfitness/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make it short, **veg*an athletes should follow the same recommendations as veg*ans that are not athletes**. Indeed, several studies have been done on the topic and here I summarize the most important ones, stating which considerations have been done for each subject:

**State of the art**

Medical science has no final assessment on veg* diets and sport.

> Little is known about the relationship between vegetarianism and
>   athletic performance.
>
> More research is needed to answer some of the current concerns of
>   vegetarian athletes.

[(Berning 2000)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470693766.ch33/summary)

> Well-controlled  long-term  studies  assessing  the  effects  of 
>   vegetarian  diets  on  athletes  have  not  been conducted.

[(Barr 2004)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15212753)

**Iron intake**

Veg* athletes must consume enough iron to meet their requirements. See below "Recommended readings" for more details.

> Potential adverse effect of a vegetarian diet on iron status is based
>   on the bioavailability of iron from plant foods rather than the amount
>   of total iron present in the diet. Vegetarian and non-vegetarian
>   athletes alike must consume sufficient iron to prevent deficiency.

[(Venderley 2006)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16573356)

**Other nutrients of concern**

Besides iron, veg* athletes must pay attention to their intake of several other micronutrients. Again, see the "Recommended readings" for the recommended intake references.

> Other nutrients of concern for vegetarian athletes include zinc,
>   vitamin B12 (cyanocobalamin), vitamin D (cholecalciferol) and
>   calcium.

[(Venderley 2006)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16573356)

> Appropriate planning and programmed follow up are needed to monitor
>   vitamin B12, iron, zinc, vitamin D, riboflavin, and protein status.

([Borrione 2009](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12534-009-0017-y); [Fuhrman 2010](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20622542))

**Creatine**

Veg* athletes might show lower creatine stores, thus a supplementation could be considered.

> Muscle creatine stores are lower in vegetarians than non-vegetarians.
>   Creatine supplementation provides ergogenic responses in
>   both vegetarian and non-vegetarian athletes, with limited data
>   supporting greater ergogenic effects on lean body mass accretion and
>   work performance for vegetarians.

[(Venderley 2006)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16573356)

**Veg* advantages**

Veg* diets show several advantages: antioxidants intake is higher and thus can prevent oxidative stress.

> Vegetarians have higher antioxidant status for vitamin C (ascorbic
>   acid), vitamin E (tocopher-ol), and β-carotene than omnivores, which
>   might help reduce exercise-induced oxidative stress.

([Venderley 2006](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16573356); [Zhou 2013](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281870423_Chapter_10_Vegetarian_Athletes))

**Macronutrients**

Macronutrient balance might be more favourable for veg*s since they eat a higher proportion of carbohydrates.

> There are advantages to the athlete of consuming a vegetarian diet.
>   Vegetarian athletes usually consume a higher proportion of energy in
>   the form of carbohydrates. It is well documented that athletes,
>   especially endurance athletes, should be consuming a higher
>   proportion of carbohydrates in their diets to maximize muscle glycogen
>   concentration.

[(Berning 2000)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470693766.ch33/summary)

**Suggested readings:**

- [Nutritional Considerations for Vegetarian Athletes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15212753)
- [Vegetarian Athletes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281870423_Chapter_10_Vegetarian_Athletes)

Comment: You should adapt your answer and post it here: http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/618/what-nutrients-should-vegetarians-supplement-while-weight-training